# Are there any rules outside of Chapter 7 of the DMG which prompt the DM to give a player an Epic Boon or Supernatural Gift?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, gm-techniques

The [Aberrant Dragonmark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/aberrant-dragonmark) feat from Ebberon, Wayfinder’s Guide to Eberron and  in Eberron: Rising from the Last War says:

> At the DM's option, a character who has the Aberrant Dragonmark feat has a chance of manifesting greater power. Upon reaching 10th level, such a character has a 10 percent chance of gaining an epic boon from among the options in chapter 7 of the Dungeon Master's Guide. If the character fails to gain a boon, they have a 10 percent chance the next time they gain a level.

What are some rules from sources other than [Chapter 7 of the DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/other-rewards#Chapter7OtherRewards),  that might prompt a DM to give players a boon or supernatural gift, from  official WotC sources only, excluding UA?

Comment: Aberrant Dragonmark was also published first online in *Wayfinder’s Guide to Eberron* and in print first in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, prior to the publication of *Wildemount*.

Comment: Should I add that?  it was my impression that neither of those are considered "official" anymore.  So I did not include them.

Comment: They are definitely official sourcebooks, though *E:RLW* has obsoleted *WGE*.

Comment: Our interactions on your last question hinted at some desire for player agency, are you interested in sources of these gifts that have no element of player agency, such as an adventure module directing the DM to award a blessing upon completion of a quest?

Comment: If I want something for my pc in game, I prefer to have a rule or basis for the request, to help convince the DM to give it to me.   So knowing what rules exist to guide dms, when fulfilling those requests, helps me better frame the way I ask the DM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all of the ways a character can gain a supernatural gift/blessing/epic boon - through class, feat, or other player facing methods?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188900/what-are-all-of-the-ways-a-character-can-gain-a-supernatural-gift-blessing-epic)

Comment: @molot no I wrote that and was told to write this new question.

Comment: Is Aberrant Dragonmark even in Explorer's Guide to Wildemount? Dragonmarks and an Eberron-specific part of the setting, so I didn't think it would be in the Wildemountt book.

Comment: @Mołot This is definitely not a duplicate. That question asks about player options, that is, choices a player can make that will gain a boon or gift. This is asking about the DM facing rules which suggest a DM grant the boon or gift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### While There Are No Other Supernatural Boons, There are Other Forms of Supernatural Gifts

There are several systems, actually, which provide effects similar to the Supernatural Gifts found in the DMG under various conditions. A good starting point, though, would be the Chwinga creature found on page 216 of Tomb of Annihilation (as well as in CM and IDRotFM), which has the following ability:

> Magical Gift (1/Day). The chwinga targets a humanoid it can see within 5 feet of it. The target gains a supernatural charm of the DM's choice. See chapter 7 of the Dungeon Masters Guide for more information on supernatural charms.

Using this ability, this creature is actually able to give out a supernatural charm to a player character (assuming that player character is of the humanoid type).

However, not every system for granting effects similar to Supernatural Gifts are just other forms of granting them. Another notable form of Supernatural Gift are those found in Mythic Odyssey of Theros, as well as the Dark Gifts from Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft (Both of which can be found in the first section, "Character Creation", of their respective books). Each of these are forms of Supernatural Gifts either granted to new characters as part of what they start with, or as rewards later on.

Similarly, a single Supernatural Gift called "Hollow One" can be found in Explorer's Guide to Wildemount (described in Section 4: Character Options), and which a character can either start with or acquire after dying and coming back.

Another source to look at for Supernatural Gifts would be Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes,  which contains Demonic Boons, as detailed in it's first chapter, "The Blood War". These boons are designed to be given out by Demonic lords to those who would serve them in order to grant them power, and can be granted at any time. However, it should be noted that these boons are described as being for use on monsters and NPCs, and are balanced accordingly.

One final source to look at is the Archdevil Charms from Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus (Found in Appendix A) which describes Charms in addition to those found in the DMG, with these specific ones being designed to be given out through infernal deals, which a player character could potentially make at any time.